# Обработка нажатий клавиш KEYCODE_DPAD_UP и KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN для TableRow

Tags: android, клавиатура

Есть таблица

```
TableLayout table
```

, заполненная TableRow.

Идёт обработка нажатий физической USB-клавиатуры, код следующий:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
...

row.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(event!=null && event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            switch (keyCode) {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                                    TableRow fromRow = (TableRow) v;
                                    int fromRowIndex = table.indexOfChild(fromRow);

                                    fromRow.requestFocus();

                                    CharSequence cellText = ((TextView) fromRow.getChildAt(2)).getText();
                                    editText.setText(cellText);

 //Далее меняем цвета у текущей строки и предыдущей выделенной строки

                                    //предыдущая строка
                                   if (lastSelectedTableItem != -1) {
                                        TableRow prevRow = ((TableRow) table.getChildAt(lastSelectedTableItem));
                                        updateRowColor(prevRow, lastSelectedRowStatus);
                                        for (int i = 0; i < prevRow.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                            TextView tv = (TextView) prevRow.getChildAt(i);
                                            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        }
                                    }
                                        lastSelectedRowStatus = finalStatus;
                                        lastSelectedTableItem = fromRowIndex;
                                        //выбранная строка
                                        fromRow.setBackgroundColor(((TextView) fromRow.getChildAt(0)).getCurrentTextColor());
                                        for (int i = 0; i < fromRow.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                            TextView tv = (TextView) fromRow.getChildAt(i);
                                            int colorCode;
                                            if (finalStatus) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                                                    colorCode = getColor(R.color.colorSelectedCell);
                                                else
                                                    colorCode = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelectedCell);
                                            } else
                                                colorCode = Color.WHITE;
                                            tv.setTextColor(colorCode);
                                        }
                                break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                                    editText.requestFocus();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Сейчас у меня проблема в следующем:

При нажатии сначала, допустим, клавиши "Вниз" (KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) (соответственно, выделяется следующая нижняя строка таблицы), а сразу после неё - клавиши "Вверх" (KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)  - выделяется снова нижняя строка, а не верхняя, как предполагается.

(Наоборот - сначала нажать Вверх,затем Вниз - аналогично - выделяется предыдущая верхняя строка, а не нижняя).

Отследить дебагом, что я делаю не так, нереально из-за подключаемой клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2):

После `case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:` должен идти `break;`, иначе, когда ты нажимаешь вниз, у тебя будет выполняться код написанный для кнопки вверх.

Кстати комп и устройство можно соединить по wi-fi в Android Studio, если у вас есть такая возможность)